# Python decorator to disable a certain function crashing

Tags: python, django, multithreading, uwsgi, python-decorators

I have a function in python that's used in many views. Specifically its in a django app running under uwsgi. The function just fires tracking data into our database. I wanted to create a decorator that would disable that function for a specific call to the view that contains the function. Essentially:

```
@disable tracking
def view(request):
   track(request) //disabled by decorator
```

The decorator works by replacing the global definition of track with a void function that does nothing. Since we're running this under uwsgi which is multithreaded if I replace a global definition it will replace the function for all threads running under the process, so I defined the decorator to only activate if the tid and pid are equivalent. Here:

```
def disable_tracking(func):
    #decorator
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        original_tracker = pascalservice.track.track
        anon = lambda *args, **kwargs: None
        tid = lambda : str(current_thread().ident)
        pid = lambda : str(getpid())
        uid = lambda : tid() + pid()
        current_uid = uid()
        cache.set(current_uid, True)
        switcher = lambda *args, **kwargs: anon(*args, **kwargs) if cache.get(uid()) else original_tracker(*args, **kwargs)
        pascalservice.track.track = switcher
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        cache.delete(current_uid)
        pascalservice.track.track = original_tracker
        return result
    return inner
```

The wierd thing about this decorated function is that I'm getting occasional crashes and I want to verify if this style of coding is correct as it's a little unconventional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is called monkey patching. While not a totally bad practice it often leads to difficult to pinpoint bugs so use it with caution.

If the decorator is mandatory for some reason I would suggest adding some flag to the request object in your decorator and add a check for that flag in your track function.

The decorator :

```
def disable_tracking(func):
  def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    kwargs["request"].pascalservice_do_not_track = true
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  return wrapper
```

Beginning of track function :

```
if hasattr(request, "pascalservice_do_not_track"):
  return
# do the tracking ...
```

You may also just comment the line calling track in your view.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Also fyi, I would just comment out the track function but actually it's being called within multiple other functions within the view. Those functions are reused in other places so can't exactly comment remove it easily.